# Issue with duplicate records in database during ETL process

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl

My current ETL architecture is as follows:

```
s3 --> staging table --> python dataframe --> destination table
```

1. Records from s3 are loaded into a staging table
2. Python script is connected to staging table
3. Python script is run every one hour to do some complex
   transformations
4. The resultant dataframe from python is uploaded into the destination
   table

However, I am having an issue with duplicate records in destination table:

```
| Time | New records (S3) | Redshift staging table (postgre) | Python DataFrame | Redshift Destination Table (postgre) | Duplicate records |
|------|------------------|----------------------------------|------------------|--------------------------------------|-------------------|
| 9am  | 3 records        | 3 records                        | 3 records        | 3 records                            | 0 (3-3)           |
| 10am | 2 records        | 5 (3+2) records                  | 5 records        | 8 (3+5) records                      | 3 (8-5)           |
| 11am | 4 records        | 9 (5+4) records                  | 9 records        | 17 (9+8) records                     | 8 (17-9)          |
```

So at 11am, the staging table had 9 records but the destination table at 17 records (total 8 duplicate records in destination table at 11am)

How can I ensure that the total records in destination table matches with those present in the staging table

( I cannot eliminate the staging table. Right now, I am filtering the destination table to select only unique records. Is there a better way to do this? )

Comment: can't you just purge the destination table before it's refilled with the new portion of data?

Comment: Which database are you using, PostgreSQL or Redshift? They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your stage and destination tables are in Postgres, so just write logic that compares the data in the stage table with the dest table and deletes any records from stage that already exist in the dest table.

```
DELETE FROM staging
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dest WHERE dest.id = staging.id);
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html